# Visual Studio / MFC: BMP fills Picture Control on desktop, but is too small on my laptop

Tags: visual-studio, bitmap, mfc

I have a number of dialogs with Picture Controls. On my Win10 desktop, the BMP correctly fills the entire picture control, but on my Win10 laptop the BMP only fills about 2/3 of the picture control.

If I change Windows 10 "Scale and layout" setting from say 100% to 125% on both my desktop and laptop, then the dialog and BMP both get bigger/smaller, but the same problem exists: the BMP is significantly smaller than the control on my laptop.

In the Picture Control properties, Image is set to an IDB bitmap resource, and Type=Bitmap.

[image: Desktop Preview]

[image: Laptop Preview]

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Could you post some screen shots?

Comment: Sure - here are two links to images of the dialog on my desktop and my laptop. Both desktop and laptop are only a few months old. 
 www.dropbox.com/s/jz3yi309tozf4my/login%20desktop.jpg?dl=0      www.dropbox.com/s/f71700f06i0r03k/login%20laptop.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I have duplicated your images into your question for ease of viewing to users.

Comment: You should also show how you have created the picture control. If it's made with resource editor, you can peek in the *.rc file, it would show something like `CONTROL IDB_BITMAP1,IDC_STATIC1,"Static",SS_BITMAP...`

Comment: It would have been created in the resource editor of an old version of VS, probably MSVC++ 6, and it says "CONTROL         IDB_LoginWinBitmap,IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_BITMAP | SS_REALSIZEIMAGE,7,7,233,62"

Comment: On a side note, why are you not [enabling visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I had never thought about it, partly because the application is over 20 years old, and frankly I know next to nothing about it. Is that something I should do? Presumably it enables Windows themes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx

You will see the following quote:

> **SS_REALSIZEIMAGE** is always used in conjunction with **SS_ICON**.

You need to change your resource setting because yours is not an icon. That article also states:

> **SS_REALSIZECONTROL**
>
> Adjusts the bitmap to *fit the size of the static control*. For example, changing the locale can change the system font, and thus controls might be resized. If a static control had a bitmap, the bitmap would no longer fit the control. This style bit dictates automatic redimensioning of bitmaps to fit their controls.
>
> If SS_CENTERIMAGE is specified, the bitmap or icon is centered (and clipped if needed). If SS_CENTERIMAGE is not specified, the bitmap or icon is stretched or shrunk.
>
> Note that the redimensioning in the two axes are independent, and the result may have a changed aspect ratio.